# C# .NET Core 6 HttpRequest convert to json for logging?

Tags: c#, json.net, httprequest, httpresponse, .net-6.0

I am using .NET Core 6 and I'm looking to convert the request and response to JSON for logging. When I use `Newtonsoft.Json` to convert the object I am getting an out of memory exception. What is the simplest and or best way to convert it without having to go through field by field?

Exception I got when trying to simply convert it.

Code of my logging middleware

```
public class RequestResponseLoggerMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly AppSettings _appSettings;
    private readonly ILogger<RequestResponseLoggerMiddleware> logger;

    public RequestResponseLoggerMiddleware(
        RequestDelegate next,
        IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings,
        ILogger<RequestResponseLoggerMiddleware> logger)
    {
        _next = next;
        _appSettings = appSettings.Value;
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        logger.LogInformation($"{JsonConvert.SerializeObject(context.Request, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings(){ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore})}");

        await _next(context);

        logger.LogInformation($"{JsonConvert.SerializeObject(context.Response, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings(){ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore})}");
    }
}
```

Error:

> Something went wrong: System.OutOfMemoryException: Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.
>
> at System.Text.StringBuilder.ExpandByABlock(Int32 minBlockCharCount)
> at System.Text.StringBuilder.Append(Char* value, Int32 valueCount)
> at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendHelper(String value)
> at System.IO.StringWriter.Write(String value)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.AutoCompleteClose(JsonContainerType type)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.WriteEnd(JsonContainerType type)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.WriteEnd()
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.AutoCompleteAll()
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.Close()
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextWriter.Close()
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.System.IDisposable.Dispose()
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObjectInternal(Object value, Type type, JsonSerializer jsonSerializer)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Object value, Type type, Formatting formatting, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Object value, Formatting formatting, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
> at API.Middleware.RequestResponseLoggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

What is the suggested / better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Another option:**

According to [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0) in `.Net 6` you can log request and response by adding `app.UseHttpLogging();` middleware.

HTTP Logging is a middleware that logs information about HTTP requests and HTTP responses. HTTP logging provides logs of:

- HTTP request information
- Common properties
- Headers
- Body
- HTTP response information

HTTP Logging is valuable in several scenarios to:

- Record information about incoming requests and responses.
- Filter which parts of the request and response are logged.
- Filtering which headers to log.

Comment: Hi, this is excellent news. My only question is where it logs to? I'm not seeing it in the terminal for my project. If it helps, I'm using VS Code.

Comment: Follow up, found I was missing this code it the appsettings.Logging.LogLevel: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpLogging.HttpLoggingMiddleware

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the information you're trying to convert is too huge. Newtonsoft.Json uses StringBuilder internally and StringBuilder generally has a limit of Int32.MaxValue. Again, this is implementation specific. Check the [StringBuilder.MaxCapacity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.maxcapacity?view=net-6.0) for your implementation.

There are two issues here:

1. The maximum number of characters that StringBuilder can hold.
2. The huge pressure on the Garbage Collector when StringBuilder dynamically keeps expanding (which I think is causing the OOM exception)

You have two options:

1. Find an alternative to NewtonSoft.Json that can handle large data elegantly. Check out [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0#:%7E:text=Json%20does%20case%2Dinsensitive%20property,it%27s%20doing%20an%20exact%20match.) which Microsoft claims to be faster and efficient.
2. Reduce the size of your payload.